# Emulator: failed to initialize WHPX: Function not implemented

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, whpx

While trying to run the emulator on the android studio I am getting the following error

```
    Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.


    Emulator: failed to initialize WHPX: Function not implemented
    Emulator: Warning: requested RAM 1536M too high for your system. Reducing to maximum supported size 512M
    Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: Could not load library WinHvPlatform.dll.
```

while running the emulator  I am getting Notification as

```
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
enter code here
Emulator: failed to initialize WHPX: Function not implemented
```

This is my first time using the android studio.Please some one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error that "Emulator: failed to initialize WHPX: Function not implemented"

Updated Android Emulater to latest update and Android SDK Platform-Tools

I found that it was simply not installed, for whatever reason.

To add it to the Android Studio installation, go to Tools->Android->SDK Manager, select the SDK Tools tab, then ensure that Android Emulator is selected.